# Finding the limit of a fraction with irrational exponent

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

I'm studying this limit:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$$
Let $\alpha\in\mathbb R$: I've divided cases for $\alpha\in\mathbb N$, $\alpha\in\mathbb Q$, $\alpha\in\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$.

If $\alpha\in\mathbb N$, no problems, for odd $\alpha$ the limit doesn't exist, for even $\alpha$ exists.

If $\alpha\in\mathbb Z-\mathbb N$ the limit exists.
If $\alpha\in\mathbb Q$ I understand how to demonstrate the existence of the limit.

But what is the limit of that function if $\alpha$ is irrational?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Even for $1/2$ the limit doesn't exists and, even for things like $2/2$ do you first square or take a square root or do does $\alpha=1/3$ give the same as $\alpha=2/6$?

Comment: Yes, @kingW3 , your comment shows how inefficient will always be any method of defining rational powers in terms of surds and exponentiations. That’s why cutting to the chase and  using $\exp(x)=e^x$ and the natural log is so much cleaner.

Comment: @Lubin $e^x$ is still multivalued and $\log$ of negative values is still undefined or multivalued, I don't think it makes it cleaner or easier, it looks like you only considered $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: @kingW3 , in no sense is $e^x$ multivalued. It *is* true that it fails to be one-to-one, but that is an entirely different issue. It’s also true that I considered positive values of $x$ only, since OP never said anything about wanting to define $x^{-\alpha}$ for $x\notin\Bbb R^{>0}$.

Comment: @Lubin I mean the $\lim_{x\to 0}$ not as $\lim_{x\to0^+} $ also the whole question of implies that he mentioned for odd/even $\alpha$ the answer is different but that's only if you consider $x$ changing sign. Anyway indeed $e^x$ is not multivalued, $\log$ is though.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather complicated, since $a^b$ is multivalued. For example, even $(-1)^{1/3}$ is not a single value; there are three possible values: $-1$, $e^{i\pi/3}$, and $e^{i5\pi/3}$.

So, let's try to define $a^b$ in a way that makes sense in regards to it being a real function. If $a>0$, then we will define $a^b$ in the standard way. If $a<0$, then the power rule for logarithms does not hold (that is, $\ln a^b\neq b\ln a)$, so we will need to use some complex analysis.

The complex logarithm $\log$ (not to be confused with the real natural logarithm $\ln$) is defined by:

$$\log(z)=\ln\lvert z\rvert+i\arg(z),$$

where $z\in\mathbb C$, $\lvert z\rvert>0$ is the modulus of $z$, and $\arg(z)=\theta+2\pi n$, where $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$ is the angle $z$ makes with the positive real axis in the complex plane and $n\in\mathbb Z$. It *is* true that $\log(a^b)=b\log(a)$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb C$.

Suppose $a<0$. Then

\begin{align*}
a^b&=e^{\log(a^b)}\\
&=e^{b\log(a)}\\
&=e^{b(\ln\lvert a\rvert+i \arg(a))}\\
&=(-a)^b\cdot e^{i(b(\pi+2\pi n))}\\
&=(-a)^b\cdot\left[\cos(b(2n+1)\pi)+i\sin(b(2n+1)\pi)\right]\\
\end{align*}

There will be at most two real solutions (one positive and/or one negative). We can define $a^b$ in the following way:

- If a real, positive solution exists, $a^b$ is that positive solution;
- Else, if a real, negative solution exists, $a^b$ is that negative solution;
- Otherwise, $a^b$ is undefined.

Now, the only way that real solutions can exist is if we have no imaginary component. That is, we need

$$\sin(b(2n+1)\pi)=0\implies b=\frac{k}{2n+1},$$

where $k\in\mathbb Z$. So, to answer one of your questions:

> $a^b$ cannot be defined as a real number if $a<0$ and $b\notin\mathbb Q$.

Now, let's suppose that $a<0$ and $b=\frac{k}{2m+1}$, for some $k,m\in\mathbb Z$. Substituting that into $a^b$ gives us

\begin{align*}
a^\frac{k}{2m+1}
&=(-a)^\frac{k}{2m+1}\cdot\left[\cos\left(\frac{k(2n+1)}{2m+1}\pi\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{k(2n+1)}{2m+1}\pi\right)\right],
\end{align*}

where $n\in\mathbb Z$. It's not too hard to show that:

- If $k$ is even, then $a^b=(-a)^b$.
- If $k$ is odd, then $a^b=-(-a)^b$

So, in conclusion, if the definition I gave is well-defined (which, to be honest, I'm not so sure that it even is), then $\lim_{x\to 0}x^{-\alpha}$ exists iff $\alpha=\frac{2s}{2t+1}$ for some integers $s,t$.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, the only way to define $x^\alpha$, when $\alpha$ is irrational, is as $\exp(\alpha\log(x))$, where by “log” I mean the natural, base-$e$ one.

Using the fact that the function $\exp$ is continuous, we write:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\,\frac1{x^\alpha}&=\lim_{x\to0}\,\exp\left(\log\left(\frac1{x^\alpha}\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\,\exp\bigl(-\alpha\log(x)\bigr)\\
&=\exp\bigl(\lim_{x\to0}-\alpha\log(x)\bigr)\\
&=\exp\bigl(-\alpha\lim_{x\to0}\log\,x\bigr)\,.
\end{align}$$
At this point, you remember what the graph of $\log$ looks like, and the fact that $\log\,x$ goes down to $-\infty$ as $x$ goes to $0$. So if $\alpha>0$, then $-\alpha<0$ and $-\alpha\log\,x$ goes to $+\infty$, as does our original limit. If $\alpha<0$, then $-\alpha$ is positive, and $-\alpha\log\,x$ goes to $-\infty$, so the value if the exponential goes to zero.

Comment: Oh great!! Now it's clear :) Thanks a lot

Comment: $\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$ does not hold for negative $a$.

Comment: If you want the logarithm to satisfy $\log(xy)=\log x+\log y$, then there is no way to define it as an honest (single-valued) function on any open subset of $\Bbb C$.